# Как растянуть сайдбар до футера, вне зависимости от количества контента на странице?

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript

Делаю тему для сайта.

Первый вопрос - как растянуть сайдбар до футера, вне зависимости от количества контента на странице?

Второй вопрос - почему на страницах [статей](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/goroda-ukrainy/lechenie-alkogolizma-zaporozhe.html) картинка уходит под сайдбар?

Третий вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы футер подстраивался под высоту контента и был прилеплен к низу экрана?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Очень нуждаюсь в помощи, перепробовал все варианты...

Comment: Хороший заголовок

* в виде вопроса, например: "Как спрашивать?";
* четкий, ясный, краткий, понятный и информативный;
* без слов вида "помогите, посоветуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, здравствуйте".

Answer (score 1):

1. http://www.getincss.ru/2009/07/11/4-sposoba-kak-sozdat-bloki-kolonki-odinakovoj-vysoty/
2. Это вы, видимо, уже исправили.
3. http://grigoriev.pw/articles/pure-sticky-footer/ , а чтоб подстраивался, напишите так:

   var footer_height = $('.footer').height();

   $('body').css('margin-bottom', footer_height);

   $('.footer').css('height', footer_height);

Как-то так. )

Comment: @Pavel_G Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: @Pavel_G этот код не делает то, что нужно мне.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение на третий вопрос:

```css
html {
  height: 100%; /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%; /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 30px; /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer */
}

footer {
  position: absolute; /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px; /* Высота footer */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```